# How do I split words in a String with JavaScript regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the String "Edit[user]", but I need get "Edit" and later "user".

How can I do it? Any help would be useful.

Of course I need do it with JavaScript regex.

Comment: This is a fairly basic regex - check out http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html for getting started with regular expressions.

Comment: are you saying you need to do it with a regexp because that's a requirement, or because you don't know any other way to go about it?

Comment: What exactly is allowed between the brackets? Only letters? Whitespace? Any other characters?

Comment: have you tried word separator `\b`?

Answer (score 4):

```
var regex = /(.+)\[(.+)\]/;
var str = "Edit[user]";
regex.exec(str); // will return ["Edit[user]", "Edit", "user"]
```

Or you could do it this way with the `String#split` method:

```
var str = "Edit[user]";
str.split(/\[(.+)\]/); // will return ["Edit", "user"]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is grouping. I'll quickly explain how these work in JavaScript and leave the actual Regular Expression up to you.

```
var myString = "cat dog frog";
var myRegexp = /(cat).*(frog)/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
```

match will be an array, index 0 will have the whole match, and any others will have the contents of the groups.

```
match[0] = "cat dog frog"
match[1] = "cat"
match[2] = "frog"
```